# Solution to put down a window sill crack to prevent mold

Tags: windows, mold, sealing, condensation

I have a couple windows where there is a space below the window that goes into the wall (see bottom of picture). There was mold and condensation all around the area, so I'm guessing there's mold down in there as well. Is there something I can put in there to kill/prevent mold before sealing that space? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like 3% hydrogen peroxide to kill mold. It doesn’t stink like bleach and won’t be a problem to seal over once dry.

Answer (score 1):

Bleach only temporarily kills mold. Peroxide actually kills it. Ozone machines kill it as well. Be very careful to not breathe the spores that rise when you clean mold. Mold is dangerous for your health. Wear a mask and soak it in peroxide first.

Comment: Is "temporarily kills mold" anything like "[mostly dead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbE8E1ez97M)"?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do anything before you have find the source and path of the water!**

Cosmetic cleaning with follow up caulking may lead to bigger problem later, if the wood frame is rotten from inside out. I suggest first to inspect carefully, on wall to window joints to locate gaps, open/deteriorated mortar joints, or defective seal. The next is to remove the window trim to inspect the wood hidden behind. If the wood is modestly moist, and it stays firm, you shall correct the defects (stop water intrusion), and let the wood dry, then apply detergent. If the wood is rotten out (very soft), you are facing the hard choices whether to replace the window, or repair. Good luck.